# Find value of limit at a certain point

Tags: limits

[image]

In this question are they asking for the limit of the fucntion as it approaches a certain point so for i) if my answer was |x-1| would that be correct or does this question require a different answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Since $f(x):=x^3$ as $x<0$, then 
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x)=0^3=0.$$ 
As $x \to 0^+$, you are right to use $f(x)=|x-1|$ ($0<x<2$), giving 
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)=|0-1|=1\neq2=f(0).$$

Comment: @Oliver Oloa, so the answer for the first one is 1? Then could i say the answer for the second limit is 2 because when x=0 , f(x) is 2?

Comment: @Daniel To me the right answers are as follows: (i)0 (ii)1 (iii)does not exist (iv)0 (v)1 (vi)1. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help this is very useful to y exam preperation

Comment: You are welcome.